# Tomcat servlet problem - class not found

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I'm trying to learn how to develop a servlet to run under Apache's Tomcat server on Windows XP. I'm using Tomcat 6.0 with Java SDK 1.6.0_17. My webapp is a simple Hello, world type which I'm building using the latest version of the Eclipse IDE. I'm able to run all the examples in the Tomcat installation but when I export my app from Eclipse to the Tomcat webapps folder and try to access it from my browser, I get errors pointing to the fact that the `javax.servlet.http.Servlet` class couldn't be found. I searched the SDK tree and couldn't find any thing with `javax` in the name so I'm guessing it isn't there.

I've googled around but haven't found anything with this exact, same issue. Any suggestions what I can try?

Comment: This sounds like something is broken.  Could you locate where the javax.servlet.http.Servlet class is used in your own code, and where the implementation Eclipse finds for it, is located (Use F3 to go there quickly and then look in the Project Explorer (if synchronized with the editor)).

Answer (score 4):

the Servlet class in servlet.jar, which is part of Java EE (the "Enterprise" part of Java) and not the regular JDK distribution. It's usually in Tomcat's classpath so once you get your app deployed to Tomcat there's little trouble finding it.

Usually, the problem with this jar is that it's not normally in Eclipse's classpath, so you end up with compile-time problems.

If it's really missing at runtime on Tomcat, try digging for it in your project's library dependencies (I can never figure out where Eclipse hides that stuff) and copy it into the "common/lib" subdirectory of your Tomcat installation.

Answer (score 2):

It should be available in servlet-api.jar in Tomcat's own classpath, i.e. the `Tomcat/lib` folder.

If you get this particular error, there's probably more at matter. You maybe duplicated one or more of Tomcat's own libraries (one of the files in `Tomcat/lib`) into Eclipse or, more worse, the `JDK/lib`. You shouldn't do that. Keep all default libraries there where they belongs. Never duplicate/move them around. Only reference them.

If you want to develop webapps using Eclipse, you should have got at least the **Eclipse for Java EE Developers** and integrated Tomcat in Eclipse through the `Servers` view and have created a `Dynamic Web Project` wherein you have selected the afore-integrated Tomcat instance as the default server instance.

For more hints about using Eclipse and Tomcat together, you may find [this tutorial](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2008/01/jsf-tutorial-with-eclipse-and-tomcat.html) useful (you may fully skip and ignore the JSF part if that is not of interest).

**Edit**: I realized that `javax.servlet.http.Servlet` class actually doesn't exist. You need either `javax.servlet.Servlet` or `javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet`. But that would already have failed during compiletime, not during runtime, so your problem was maybe not described very accurate.

Comment: One correction to that: The servlet-api.jar is servlet.jar's little brother: It satisfies the dependencies enough to avoid compile errors, so it's usually in Eclipse's build path; but for the actual functionality, one needs servlet.jar to be available where the webapp is running.

Comment: The filename is appserver specific. Tomcat doesn't have a servlet.jar, but calls it servlet-api.jar.

Comment: addendum: and Eclipse can only find it if you integrated the server in Eclipse and associated it with the project. You should NOT manually copy/reference it in Eclipse build path or so.